# Need help in representing time in chart when user is online

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to represent user's online timing into a graph.

Suppose a user comes online at 2:10 and s/he is online till 2:30 and again comes online at 2:50 and chats till 3:00.

In the graph I want on x-axis infinite time and on y-axis true(1) or false(0) value, when user is online then its true otherwise false.

Here is pictorial representation:

[image]

I was trying to use chart.js but it dosen't seems to working for me in this scenario.

Here is jsfiddle link: [graph](http://chu.pe/5my)

I am able to fetch status when user comes online.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) You can costumize a lot of stuff and work it with JavaScript Libraries or Server Side Languages :)

Comment: I'll throw in a recommendation also, one of the most popular data visualization tools is d3 (Which you'll be able to get a great deal of help online with when facing issues due to it's popularity), here's a link to some examples 
 - https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: What do you mean infinite time on x axis..after all there is just 24hrs in a given

Comment: infinite time means one day after another day and continues this, like 28-Jun-2017 12:53:50, 29-Jun-2017 11:45:5, etc

Comment: for now can you please help me for just 24 hours on the x-axis.